# How to convert setData to transaction in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
database
          .collection('details')
          .document(userId)
          .setData(
        {
          "othernames": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
            [
              {
                "name": name,
              },
            ],
          ),
        },
        merge: true,
      );
```

I don't know to convert this to transaction. 
The transaction has only `set` and `update`.
The document will not be exist and i can't use update.
It has to be created

Comment: What do you mean by "transaction"?

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this?

```
final docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('details').doc()
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
  DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await tx.get(docRef);
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    await transaction.update(docRef, {
      'othernames': FieldValue.arrayUnion(
        [
          {
            "name": name,
          },
        ],
      )
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: yes. but the document id does not exist (Document does not exist with such an id for the first time.). That is why i use `setData`. In such case how do i do it?

Comment: just leave the document id blank, you'll get an generated id. or you can just set an id you want. you can get more from the documentation, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data